# FTP uploading from iPhone app is stuck - BlackRaccoon

Tags: ios, file-upload, ftp, blackraccoon

I'm using BlackRaccoon from @Lloyd-Sargent for photos uploading. I'm having a strange problem:
In my development environment uploading was/is working fine, but then I uploaded the binary to iTunes and after approval I checked the uploading feature was not working.
I thought that it might be some issue in the binary, then again I tested the app and uploaded the binary. The uploading on the approved binary is still not working.

I checked the app log using console:
no images are uploaded.
neither requestCompleted nor requestFailed is fired.

I'm stuck please help.